# Powershell equivalent of simple DOS command-line: "copy *.ps1 *.ps1.bak /y"

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm still learning Powershell; and, realize it was designed to be very simple.  But, I'm embarrassed to say I can't figure out a simple way to do the below dos copy command using powershell cmdlets (simplest way possible).  It seems as that copy-item doesn't like wildcards very much.  The things I tried ended up being overly complex; and, still didn't do what I really wanted it to do.

**copy *.ps1 *.ps1.bak /y**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in Copy-Item command doesn't do this but it isn't hard to get the desired functionality with a little script:

```
Get-ChildItem *.ps1 | Copy-Item -Dest {"${_}.bak"}
```

The use of `Foreach-Object` isn't necessary in this case because the `Destination` parameter accepts pipeline input as well.  For parameters that accept pipeline input we can use a scriptblock to compute the value for the parameter. PowerShell maps `$_` to the pipeline object for use inside the scriptblock as if we were doing this in a `Foreach-Object` scriptblock.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I tried this today on a different machine, I got the below error message.  The only way I could make it work is by changing $_ to $_.name **Copy-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'Destination' failed. Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:39
+ Get-ChildItem *.ps1 | Copy-Item -Dest {$_ + ".bak"}**

Comment: Yeah it is probably best to evaluate $_ inside a string (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I don't have a Windows machine handy, but have you tried something like:

```
Get-ChildItem *.ps1 | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_ "$_.bak"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
copy-item -rec -filter *.ps1 C:\Source C:\Dest
```

**update:**

```
a = Get-Item .\*.ps1

foreach($file in $a)
{
   Copy-Item $file.FullName "C:\mydir\$($file.Name.replace(".ps1",".ps1.bak");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keith's solution is my favorite but here's what I would have suggested:

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem *.ps1) { copy $i "$i.bak" }
```